# Cucumber and ruby: print every step executed

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, cucumber, watir-webdriver

With the function below, I can receive a print of the last execution of the test, however I want to learn how to receive a print at every step executed by the automation.

How can this be done?

**env.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
```

**hooks.rb**

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'json'
require 'magic_encoding'
require 'win32console'
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'


browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.driver.manage.window.maximize

Before do 
@browser
    @browser = browser
  end

After do |_scenario|
  browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
  embed 'screenshot.png', 'image/png'
end
```

**login.rb**

```
given("que estou na tela de login") do

            @browser.goto "url"

         #I want a screenshot of this step

end
```

Comment: You normally can't do that unless the tool supports it. You'll have to stub in lots and lots of "log now" statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `AfterStep` hook if you want to do an action after each step - eg:

```
AfterStep do
  browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
end
```

Comment: It did not work and it did not give an error, it only had the same behavior as the code I already have, it takes the print of the last step executed.